# Dynamically adding a Form with AngularJs based on another input

Tags: angularjs

In my application I have a number picker and which you can increase and decrease thanks to [Maike Daloo](http://maikeldaloo.com/post/angularjs-counter-directive)

Now I am trying to loop through the number and create form with inputs so that I can fill out the form and be able to post it.

### [Here is a Bin example](http://jsbin.com/mutigomuco/1/edit?html,js,output) of what I want to do

#### Q1

Can I dynamically add html from a controller?

#### Q2

Should I be using a directive and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you built an array of adults, `myAdults`, and then `ng-repeated` the form, like such: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/hapodatubi/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<form ng-repeat="adult in myAdults">
  <h4>Hello</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
      Email
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" ng-model="adult.name" placeholder="Email"
             id="inputEmail" class="form-control" />
      {{adult}}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the JS:

```
$scope.adults = 4;
$scope.children = 2;
$scope.myAdults = [];

for (i = 0; i < $scope.adults; i ++) {
  $scope.myAdults.push({});
}
```

So:

**Can I dynamically add html from a controller?** Yes, but you shouldn't

**Should I be using a directive and how can I do it?** If you went the route of dynamically generating the HTML, yes you should, if you go the route of using the built in `ng-repeat`, no need.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. Now I can have `ng-model=""` inside the inputs or even the outer container because I will need it later on.